# C# Importing text from my winform textbox to selected range in already openend Excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, import, ms-office

Trying to have a value in my winform textbox written to one or more selected cells in excel.

Scenario:

1. Open an excel file using windows explorer (so no coding here)
2. Select a cell in this excel file's sheet( I know selecting multiple cells could be a problem, but I want to solve that later on)
3. Open my winform app (let's call it LookApp for reference)
4. Do stuff in the app so that a textbox contains a string(let's call the string ProductCode for referencing)
5. Press a button on the LookApp
6. The string Productcode is inserted into the selected cell
7. Excel gets focus over LookApp

Obviously, I can handle step 1 to 5. But I've searched the web far and wide and can't find a snippet in the direction of coding step 6.
Probably easy to code step 7 once I know step 6...

I am new to coding with MSOffice, or outside of winform/database anyways.
I have refenced MS Interop in my project but don;t know how to use it :(

I really hope you can help!

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302084) it will get you started with Excel and C#

Comment: @sco, although great to get started with, for wich thanks, it doesn't hold information on how to find the selected cell in an already opened excel worksheet... Any tips in that direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, yet it seems a little comlicated...

Stumbled upon bits of code and mixed them all up till it worked: 
The try-catch is far from beautiful, but it works...

```
        private void cbCopyToExcel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        try
        {
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlApp.ActiveCell;
            xlRange.Value = tbProductcode.Text;
        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Be sure to open an Excel file first");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an Excel Range field in your class (Form, etc...)

```
Range currentCellRange;
```

Then register to Excel's WorkSheet *SelectionChange* event

```
exWs.SelectionChange += exWs_SelectionChange;
```

in *exWs_SelectionChange* method, assign the current cell Range to your *currentCellRange* field

```
void exWs_SelectionChange(Range target)
{
    currentCellRange = target;
}
```

And when your button is pressed use the WorkSheet at the currentCellRange position's row and column to set the value of the cell.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    exWs.Cells[currentCellRange.Row, currentCellRange.Column].Value = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Also, when you're done with Excel, remember to call `Quit()` on the Application instance.